# How can I implement html code in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to run the HTML code when the condition in javascript is OK.
 this is the javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
         if(window.location.href.indexOf("index.php") > -1) {
          alert("you are in index page");
                 }
             });
              </script>
```

this is the HTML code.

```
<li class="current">  <a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "run HTML code"? HTML isn't really code. Do you want to show the HTML elements? Hide them?

Comment: `$('a[href="index.php"]').parent('li').addClass('current');`?

Answer (score 0):

Just append the HTML to the body or any other element on the match of the condition.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("index.php") > -1) {
   $('body').append('<li class="current">  <a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>');
}
```